# Web3 ReactNative Error Secure random number generation is not supported by this browser

Tags: react-native, web3js

I create RN wallet app, add web3 to generate an Ethereum account, and transfer coin/token by following instruction https://levelup.gitconnected.com/tutorial-how-to-set-up-web3js-1-x-with-react-native-0-6x-2021-467b2e0c94a4

but I got an error:

> Error: Secure random number generation is not supported by this
> browser. Use Chrome, Firefox or Internet Explorer 11

Also, test with https://medium.com/@talaikis/react-native-0-60-4-with-web3-js-1-2-0-8090a1decee2

Even add https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-random package but same issue.

Please note that when debug in browser work fine, but does not work on real mobile phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem solved when add https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-crypto package and change following lines

```
require('crypto');

// to 

import crypto from 'crypto'
```

Comment: This got rid of the error but now a new one: 
`null not an object, error evaluating RNRandomBytes.seed`....

I've searched so much and nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

React has a separate csprng package.

Use it to generate 16 bytes of randomness and pass it to bip39.entropyToMnemonic it will give you 12 word phrase. 32 bytes if you want 24 words. I think it is called rn-randombytes.